# mongoid and validates_associated does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I'm using rails 3.2 and I building a nested form. But things are not working as I expect. First of all, my model is a Company with has many Addresses. Here is the model

```
class Company
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    field :name,                        :type => String
    field :description,         :type => String
    field :order_minimun,       :type => Float

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :addresses

    validates_presence_of :name, :description, :order_minimun
  validates_length_of :name, minimum:2, maximum: 30
  validates_length_of :description, minimum:5, maximum: 140
    validates :order_minimun, :numericality => { :only_integer => true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0 }

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
    validates_associated :addresses

end

class Address
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps
    include Mongoid::Spacial::Document


    field :street,      :type => String
    field :number,      :type => Integer

    field :phone,           :type => String

    field :location,        :type => Array,     spacial: {lat: :latitude, lng: :longitude, return_array: true }

    embeds_many :delivery_zones


    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :city

    has_many :openingTimeRange

    validates_presence_of :street, :number
  validates_length_of :street, minimum:1, maximum: 30
    validates_length_of :number, minimum:1, maximum: 6
    validates_length_of :phone, minimum:5, maximum: 60


    attr_accessible :street, :number, :company_id, :city_id, :location, :phone, :delivery_zones, :latitude, :longitude

end
```

As you can see the Company model has:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :addresses
validates_associated :addresses
```

So, I think a can build a nested form. Here is the code of the form

```
<%= form_for [:admin,@company],:url =>admin_company_path(@company), :html => {:class => "form-horizontal"}  do |f|%>

    <legend><%= t '.legend' %></legend>

    <%= group_input_field f, :name%>

    <%= group_field_for f, :description do%>
        <%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 5%>
    <% end -%>

    <%= group_input_field f, :order_minimun%>

    <%= f.fields_for :addresses do |builder|%>
        <%= render 'address_fields', :f=> builder%>
    <% end %>

    <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-large', :disable_with => t('button.saving') %>
        <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                admin_companies_path, :class => 'btn btn-large btn-danger' %>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

the _address_fields.html.erb

```
<%= group_input_field f, :street%>
<%= group_input_field f, :number%>
```

I have a simple helper to generate the form fields with bootstrap

```
def group_input_field(f,field, options={})
    has_error = f.object.errors.has_key? field
    klass = has_error ? "control-group error": "control-group"
    content_tag(:div, :class => klass) do
        f.label(field, :class => 'control-label')+
        content_tag(:div, :class => 'controls') do
            f.text_field(field, :class => 'input')+
            show_error(f.object,field,has_error)+
            show_help(options)
            end
        end
end
```

Finaly the controller:

```
class Admin::CompaniesController < ApplicationController

    def new
        #crea una nueva compañia
        @company = Company.new
    end

    def edit
        @company = Company.find params[:id]
    end

    def create
        @company = Company.new(params[:company])
        if @company.save
            redirect_to :action => 'index'
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def update
        @company = Company.find(params[:id])
        if @company.update_attributes(params[:company])
            redirect_to :action => 'index'
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end

end
```

What is happening a couple of things. First, I have a company with two addresses, and I am able to edit the first one, any change on the second one is not persisted. Then the addresses fields are not validated (if i leave everything in blank when i open the form again the addresses were not save and I can see the original values). And when edit a field in any address, and any field value of the company is not valid, after the form is submited i can see the errors on the company model, but the address are displayed with the original values, so the edited values were lost.

Hope be clear.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I've found the answer. I was using the version of mongoid 3.0.4. I run the command bundle update mongoid and mongoid was updated to the version 3.0.6. And the problems were fixed.

Thanks. Hope it helps